# Proof of Bertrand test of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How to prove the Bertrand convergence test that states:

*If there exists such limit that* $$\lim_{n\to\infty}((n(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1)-1)\ln{n})=q$$ *then the series* $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1}=a_n$, *where* $a_n>0, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ *, converges if* $q>1$ *and diverges if* $q<1$.

The problem is from the book Drugi, D., *Collection of Problems in Mathematical Analysis* (in Serbian),  Naša Knjiga D.O,O., 2003, pp. 38, problem 16.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [**This**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067) will help you recognise and resolve the issues.

Comment: Also, note that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)-1\right)\log n\right]=q\quad\iff\quad a_n=\frac{1}{n(\log n)^{q+o(1)}},$$

Comment: @OliverDíaz  and @ SangchulLee the book from which I got this problem just asks for this proof without anything previously mentioned about it and I couldn't come up with any ideas how to solve it.

Comment: @OliverDíaz here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmtjqve9376ddim/ljasko-2.pdf?dl=0 page 38, problem 16. I'm not sure if anyone can access it other than me, first time using dropbox, so please tell me if you can't. Also there might be a foreign language barrier, I couldn't find the book int english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have preference for considering rations $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ instead of $\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}$. The former setting is in a way more consistent with how ratio test in presented in Calculus courses,  the latter setting is used in the following Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Extensions_to_the_ratio_test).

All the result will be presented in the former setting. It is not too difficult to make the appropriate modifications to express the results the way if Wikipedia.

---

Bertrand's and Raabe's tests can be viewed as particular instances of Kummer's test:

> **Kummer:**   Let $\sum_na_n$ be a series with terms in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $b_n$ a sequence of positive numbers.
>
> - (a) If there is $r>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
>   \begin{align}
>     b_n-b_{n+1}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\geq r,\qquad n\geq N\tag{1}\label{one}
>   \end{align}
>   then  $\sum_na_n$ is absolutely convergent.
> - (b) If there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
>   \begin{align}
>     b_n-b_{n+1}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\leq 0,\qquad n\geq N\tag{2}\label{two}
>     \end{align}
>   and $\sum_n\frac1{b_n}$ diverges, then  $\sum_n|a_n|$ diverges.

Proof: (a) For all $n\geq N$,
$$b_n|a_n|-b_{n+1}|a_{n+1}|\geq r|a_n|\geq0$$
Adding terms from between $N$ and $N$ yields
$$b_N|a_N|\geq b_N|a_N|-b_{n+1}|a_{n+1}|\geq r\sum^n_{k=N}|a_k|$$
This shows that $\sum^n_{k=1}|a_k|$ is a bounded monotone nondecreasing sequence.

(b) It follows that formal $n\neq N$
$$\frac{|a_n|}{1/b_n}\leq \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{1/b_{n+1}}$$
Thus, the sequence $n\mapsto \frac{|a_n|}{1/b_n}$ is monotone nondecreasing and bounded below; hence
$$c\frac{1}{b_n}\leq |a_n|,\qquad n\geq N$$
for some $c>0$. The conclusion follows from comparison.

---

The sequence $b_n=(n-1)\log(n-1)$ corresponds to Bertrand's test.

> **Bertrand:** Suppose $|a_n|>0$ for all $n\geq N$
>
> - (c) If $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\leq 1-\frac1n-\frac{q_n}{n\log n}$ such that $q_n\geq q>1$ for all $n\geq N$, then $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely.
> - (d) If $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\geq 1-\frac1n-\frac{q_n}{n\log n}$ such that $q_n\leq q<1$ for all $n\geq N$, then $\sum_n|a_n|$ diverges.
>   In many instances, > In many instances,  one has $$\lim_n n\log n\big(1 -\tfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\big)-\log n =q $$
>   exists. If $q>1$, then $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges while if $q<1$, $\sum_n|a_n|$ diverges. When $q=1$, the test is inconclusive.

*Proof:*
(c) implies that if $n\geq N$
$$(n-1)\log(n-1) -n\log(n)\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\geq q_n+\log\big(1-\tfrac1n\big)^{n-1}\geq q+\log\big(1-\tfrac1n\big)^{n-1}$$
As $\log\big(1-\tfrac1n\big)^{n-1}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}-1$, there is $N'\geq N$ such that $\log\big(1-\tfrac1n\big)^{n-1}>-1-\frac{q-1}{2}$ for $n\geq N'$. Hence, for $n\geq N'$
$$(n-1)\log(n-1) -n\log(n)\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\geq q-1-\frac{q-1}{2}=\frac{q-1}{2}>0$$

(d) implies that if $n\geq N$
$$(n-1)\log(n-1) -n\log(n)\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\leq q_n+\log\big(1-\tfrac1n\big)^{n-1}\leq q+\log\big(1-\tfrac1n\big)^{n-1}$$
As $\log\big(1-\tfrac1n\big)^{n-1}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}-1$, there is $N'\geq N$ such that $\log\big(1-\tfrac1n\big)^{n-1}<-1+\frac{1-q}{2}$ for $n\geq N'$. Hence, for $n\geq N'$
$$(n-1)\log(n-1) -n\log(n)\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\leq  q+\log\big(1-\tfrac1n\big)^{n-1}<-\frac{1-q}{2}<0$$

---

The sequence $b_n=n-1$ corresponds to Raabe's test:

> **Raabe:**  Suppose$|a_n|>0$ for all $n\geq N$.
>
> - (e) If $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\leq 1-\frac{p}{n}$ for some $p>1$, $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely.
> - (f) If $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\geq 1-\frac{p}{n}$ for some $p\leq1$, $\sum_n|a_n|$ diverges.
>
> In many instances,  one has $$q=\lim_n n\big(1-\tfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\big)$$ exists. If $q>1$, $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges while if $q<1$, $\sum_n|a_n|$ diverges. When $q=1$,  the test is inconclusive.

*Proof:* Let $b_b=n-1$.

(e) implies that
$$ b_n- b_{n+1}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\geq p-1>0$$

(f) implies that
$$b_n- b_{n+1}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\leq p-1\leq 0$$

---

**Comment:**
Notice that the limit version of Bertrand's theorem can be seen as an improvement to Raabe's test when the latter fails:

$$\lim_n n\log n\Big(1-\tfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\Big)-\log n=\lim_n\Big(n\big(1-\tfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\big)-1\Big)\log n$$